# Tool for automatic translation of stored procedures to plain SQL for MS-SQL CE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-ce

Given I have an application using an MS-SQL database with stored procedures and I would now also like to support the MS-SQL CE version which does not support stored procedures. What I was just thinking of was I could intercept the queries and replace calls to stored procedures with plain SQL. Is there a tool which does provide this functionality? Is there a library which can automatically translate the definition of a stored procedure to a plain SQL query?

Is such an approach possible? What are possible drawbacks? Are there any tools that would help here?

Comment: Stored procedures are much more powerful than just individual SQL queries.  Such an approach is not possible.

Comment: I know but can the same functionality with the same result not be achieved by plain SQL? Even if it is a lot of SQL statements and slower execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SQL Server Compact only can execute a single statement per call to ExecuteReader/ExecuteNonQuery, you will have to spilt your logic between code and SQL calls for SQL CE. There are no tools to help you do this.